# pythonic way to compare compound classes?

Tags: python

I have a class that acts as an item in a tree:

```
class CItem( list ):
  pass
```

I have two trees, each with CItem as root, each tree item has some dict members (like item._test = 1). Now i need to compare this trees. I can suggest to overload a comparison operator for CItem:

```
class CItem( list ):
  def __eq__( self, other ):
    # first compare items as lists
    if not list.__eq__( self, other ): return False
    # now compare dict members
    if self.__dict__ != other.__dict__: return False
    # seems equal
    return True
```

Now i can compare two trees using '==' or '!='. Is this a 'pythonic' way or such comparsion can be done easire?

Comment: What does equivalence mean in the context of the intended application? If two trees have the same structure, are they equivalent? If the nodes are the same but the ordering is different, are they equivalent?

Comment: exactly same structure, including ordering ( afaik, list.__eq__() checks order )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My feeling would be something like

```
class CItem(list):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return list.__eq__(self, other) and self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
```

but it's basically the same code you have, just expressed in shorter notation. I can't think of any more substantial changes to make offhand.